# Showing that $\mu(A) = \mu(B) \implies \mu(A\Delta B) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. I have already managed to show that $\mu(A\Delta B) = 0 \implies \mu(A) = \mu(B)$, and I would like to show the converse $\mu(A) = \mu(B) \implies \mu(A\Delta B) = 0$.

Due to $A \Delta B = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A) = \{x\in A\cup B\mid \chi_A(x) \neq \chi_B(x)\} = S$, I would like to show that $\mu(S) = 0$. Unfortunately I am not sure how to proceed with the proof. The only other thing I know is that if we were to integrate over $X$, we know that $\int_X\chi_{A\Delta B}d\mu = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - 2\mu(A\cap B) = 2(\mu(A) - \mu(A\cap B))$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is false. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $\mu (A\Delta B)=\mu(A)+\mu (B)$ because $A\Delta B=A \cup B$.

Specific example: In $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure take $A=[0,\frac  1 2)$ and $B=[\frac  1 2, 1]$. Then $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\frac 1  2$ but $\mu (A \Delta B)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B-A)$$
$$\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(B) + \mu(A-B)$$
So if $\mu(A)=\mu(B) \Rightarrow \mu(B-A)= \mu(A-B)\Rightarrow \mu(A\Delta B)=2\,\mu(A-B)$ wich is zero if and only if $\mu(A-B)=0$. But in general it may not be zero, for example if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint as mentioned by geetha290krm